# example of two continuous real-valued functions whose product is 0

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Is there an example of two continuous real-valued functions, say on some interval, whose product is 0?

Comment: I assume you want $f$ and $g$ to have only (say) countably many zeroes, otherwise it is trivial (taking $f$ and $g$ to have disjoint support).

Comment: i read (cant remember where) that if u consider the the set of continuous functions as a ring, its possible. it seems strange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

consider the interval [0,1]. define 2 continuous functions f and g. let f and g be bump functions such that their bumps are nonzero on opposite halves of the interval. then their  product is 0.

Answer (score 2):

Try
$f(x)=|x|+x$ and $g(x)=|x|-x$.

Comment: That's a bit cheating: $f$ is $0$ on $\mathbb{R}_-$, while $g$ is $0$ on $\mathbb{R}_+$

Comment: Well @Clement: there's no possible way to do it essentially otherwise as the functions must be *continuous* .

Comment: Indeed -- I assumed that was the intended meaning of the OP's question, to which the answer is "no"...

Comment: @ClementC. Cheating would be to let $f(x)=0$ :)

Answer (score 0):

On, say, $[0, 1]$, take
\begin{align*}
f(x) &= \begin{cases}
  1 - 2x & \text{if $x \leq \frac{1}{2}$;} \\
  0 & \text{if $x \geq \frac{1}{2}$}
\end{cases}
&
g(x) &= \begin{cases}
 0 & \text{if $x\leq \frac{1}{2}$;} \\
 2x - 1 & \text{if $x\geq \frac{1}{2}$.}
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
It's easy to promote them to be smooth rather than merely continuous, or to eliminate the common zero at $x = \frac{1}{2}$, if desired.